# Mod Rewrite show private file access denied

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, symlink

I have the following mod rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/../application/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ([\w]+\/www\/(.*)) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/../../application/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1
```

My server directory layout is like so:

```
/application
--/example
----/www
------/test.jpg
/www <- public root
--/.htaccess
--/index.php
```

Basically, the idea is, you access the index.php like so:

```
example.com/test/paths/ < would pass test/paths/ to index.php

example.com/example/www/test.png < would pass example/www/test.png to index.php

example.com/example/www/test.jpg < would output the contents of test.jpg
```

Now the first two examples work perfectly. When we get to the last example which would output the contents of test.jpg (which is in a non public directory), I get this error:

**You don't have permission to access /C:/web/git/framework/application/example/www/test.jpg on this server.**

I could pass this to another public php file which would then just do a file_get_contents of the private file and show it that way but I would ideally not want to spawn additional php processes. Is there anyway I can do what i want without the access denied part?

**Edit**

I have solved the problem by approaching it differently. I moved the entire applications directory into the www directory and now I use this HT ACCESS file to  only load files within a \w/www/* directory

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[\w]+/www/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/applications/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ([\w]+\/www\/(.*)) /applications/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1
```

Comment: _Why_ do you place resources that should be available via HTTP outside of the document root?

Comment: In my framework, you can have many "applications" and in each application there is the MVC files and other php stuff and a "www" folder which stores all the assets. the idea is an application is simply drag and drop and the framework takes care of the rest. the framework files and application files are not public for security reasons but i want the "www" folder to be publicly accessible

Comment: Defining an `ALIAS` would be the thing to do then, I’d say – but be aware that this is only possible in the server config, not via .htaccess - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Comment: Once someone downloads any file off of the internet you should assume its public... regardless of whether it is streamed, linked, or embedded.

Comment: I realise that, but I only want the assets within the applications www folder to be public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by approaching it differently. I moved the entire applications directory into the www directory and now I use this HT ACCESS file to only load files within a \w/www/* directory

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[\w]+/www/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/applications/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ([\w]+\/www\/(.*)) /applications/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1
```

Comment: I cannot accept my own answer before two days, but i see your point